# Hidden value requires to be send twice

Tags: php

Basically I make a calculation and use a hidden value to put it into an input field.
So I've tried to recreate my problem in the code below as to not give away the actual code I'm working with since it's a bit more sensitive.
The question is whether it's possible to get the hidden value inside the disabled box without having to click the send button twice. 
If I'm asking the impossible just say so I'll figure something out.

```
<form action='test.php' method='post'>

<?php
@$result = @$_POST['number1'] * @$_POST['number2'];

echo "<input type='text' name='number1'>
<input type='text' name='number2'>
<input type='text' value='"; if(isset($_POST['value'])) echo $_POST['value']; echo"' disabled>
<input type=hidden name='value' value='" . $result . "'>"

?>
<br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: You can get the value with Javascript on the client side and do something with it (for example use AJAX to send it to a PHP script on the server), but you would need to submit the form to actually get the value with PHP alone. What are you trying to achieve...?

Answer (score 0):

do you expect the $result in the disabled input if the $_POST["value"] is not set?

```
echo "<input type='text' value='" .(isset($_POST['value'])?$_POST['value']:$result)."' disabled>";
```

Comment: No, if you run the script you'll see that you need to click send twice to get the output in that field, I want to change it so you only have to click send once.